# Remove the required attribute after the sucees of form submission

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, forms

I have a form on click of submit the input box is highlighted with the red color border if it is empty. Now i have jquery ajax form submission on success of the form i will display a message "data submitted" and i will reset the form so all the  input fields will be highlighted in red color. Now i want to empty the fields after the success of form submission and it should not be highlighted in red color.

HTML

```js
(function() {
  'use strict';
  window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    var form = document.getElementById('index-validation');
    form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
      if (form.checkValidity() === false) {
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();
      }
      form.classList.add('was-validated');
    }, false);
  }, false);
})();

$(".index-form").submit(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  return false;
}
else {
  var ins_date = new Date($.now()).toLocaleString();
  var parms = {
    name: $("#name").val(),
    email: $("#email").val(),
    inserted_date: ins_date
  };
  var url2 = "http://localhost:3000/api";
  $.ajax({
    method: 'POST',
    url: url2 + "/homes",
    async: false,
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    data: JSON.stringify(parms),
    success: function(data) {
      console.log('Submission was successful.');
      $(".alert-success").removeClass("d-none");
      $(".alert-success").fadeTo(2000, 500).slideUp(500, function() {
        $(".alert-success").slideUp(500);
      });
      $('.index-form')[0].reset();
      console.log(data);
    },
    error: function(data) {
      console.log('An error occurred.');
      console.log(data);
    },
  })
}
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="container index-form" id="index-validation" novalidate>
  <input class="form-control" type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Your name" required>
  <input class="form-control" type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email Address" required>
  <div class="invalid-feedback">Please Enter a Valid Email Id.</div>
  <input type="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-lg btn-block text-center" value="Send">
</form>
```

Comment: `async: false` should never be used

Comment: Put this line after success promise $(".index-form")[0].reset(); OR $(".index-form").find('input').prop('required',false);

Answer (score 0):

I'm not clear with your question, Do you want to reset form or remove the error class. But anyways I'll try solving out both :

SCRIPT

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
                  (function() {
                  'use strict';
                  window.addEventListener('load', function() {
                    var form = document.getElementById('index-validation');
                    form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
                      if (form.checkValidity() === false) {
                        event.preventDefault();
                        event.stopPropagation();
                      }
                      form.classList.add('was-validated');
                    }, false);
                  }, false);
                })();

          $(".index-form").submit(function(e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
               return false;
            } else {
                    var ins_date=new Date($.now()).toLocaleString();
                 var parms = {
                 name : $("#name").val(),
                 email : $("#email").val(),
                 inserted_date:ins_date
                 };
                 var url2="http://localhost:3000/api";
                 $.ajax({
                 method: 'POST',
                 url: url2 + "/homes",
                 async: false,
                 dataType : "json",
                 contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                 data: JSON.stringify(parms),
                 success: function(data){
                 console.log('Submission was successful.');
    //if you are removing specific property from class
                $(".alert-success").css('display', 'none');
                  $(".alert-success").fadeTo(2000, 500).slideUp(500, function(){
                  $(".alert-success").slideUp(500);
                 });     
$("form")[0].reset(); 
                 console.log(data);
                 }, error: function (data) {
                    console.log('An error occurred.');
                    console.log(data);
                       },   
                    })
                 }
              });
              </script>
```

Jquery doesn't support any method such as reset() of javascript, So you can trigger javascript's reset() method.

Feel free to ask doubts if stuck. Happy coding....!!!!!

Comment: I have tried it is not working. My question is after the success of form submission i need to show the success message and the form should reset

Comment: is success message coming ??

Comment: try this $("form")[0].reset(); This will surely work because Jquery doesn't have a reset() function . So instead of picking element by class, try picking up the node

Comment: Then try solution provided by ChaN which is basic, straight forward, just reset the input boxes one by one

Answer (score 0):

```
$(this.('.index-form').find("input[type=text]").val("");
```

You can just empty the form value by giving the .val() as empty, you have to give this on after your ajax response.
and also instead of using fade in and fade out just try to use hide and show function both may work like same.

Comment: if i empty the form then the input is highlighted with red color border

Comment: use triggger event it can help u in it

Comment: gave a try like this , at  end of that function just mention returm false that can stop that highlight